# Unit testing : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

### Getting below error when I run npm test

### TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') in angular

service.ts file

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private fhirServcie: FHIRService) {
}

tokenResponse:any = this.fhirServcie.getTokenResponse();

getCarePlanDetails(): Observable<any> {
...
}
```

FHIR.service.ts

```
   public fhirClient!: Client;
   
   setFhirClient(client: Client) {
        this.fhirClient = client
   }
   getTokenResponse() {
        return this.fhirClient.state.tokenResponse;
    }
```

service.spec.ts file

```
describe('CarePlanService', () => {
  let service: CarePlanService;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let mockFhirService: jasmine.SpyObj<FHIRService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        { provider: FHIRService, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('FHIRService', ['getTokenResponse']) }]
    });
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.get(CarePlanService);
    mockFhirService = TestBed.get(FHIRService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

sample Client object is like,

```
{ "state":{
 "tokenResponse": {
      "access_token": "fsdjfhsjkfk" }
  }}
```